# in Xcode 5.1.1 interface builder, controls disappear when resized. Why?

Tags: interface, builder, xcode5.1

when using Xcode 5.1.1 interface builder, controls disappear when resized.  This did not happen in previous versions of Xcode.  Also, resizing a control on a window in interface builder causes the whole window to move.  This also did not happen in previous versions.  Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a little too late, but if someone else encounter the same problem...
Reverting to the original settings of Xcode solved the problem for me. Just write in Terminal.app:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
```